# Continuously print stdout and write to file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that will intermittently print to stdout. I want to see the output on the screen AND redirect it to a file.

I can use `tee` as follows:

```
foo | tee ./log.txt
```

However, this would print the output to the screen only when `foo` has terminated not allowing me to observe the progress of my program.

Is there a way to continuously show the output of the program and redirect it to a log file?

Comment: You're probably seeing the effects of libc using a 4k output buffer, if stdout is connected to a pipe rather than a tty.  So you don't necessarily have to wait for `foo` to terminate, but for it to generate 4k of output.   There are a few workarounds in the answers to this question:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: Running `foo` as standalone will not produce this effect though (will continuously print). Is it still due to the buffer?

Comment: Yes, if you're running `foo` standalone, output is going to a tty, and you'll get the usual line-oriented buffering.  If you redirect it to a file or a pipe, then libc detects that the output isn't a tty,  and switches to a 4k output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable to write output to a file and display it live ?

```
$> foo > ./log.txt & tail -f ./log.txt
```